# Access Denied in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i have some problem in vb.net and it says "Access Denied ......"

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class koneksi
    Public conn As MySqlConnection
    Dim database As String = "server=192.168.0.199;database=db_wafiq;uid=***;pwd=***;"
    Public Sub konek()
        Try
            conn = New MySqlConnection(database)
            conn.Open()
            MsgBox("Koneksi Berhasil")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            conn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

My Code :

[image]

[image]

My Error Message :

[image]

Comment: related: https://forums.asp.net/t/1999254.aspx?Timeout+in+IO+operation+Mysql+connection

Comment: Where does it say that? In the message box? If so then it would appear that an exception was thrown by your database server. You need to look more closely that the exception to determine ALL the relevant information you can.

Comment: By the way, I edited out your database credentials. Don't post that sort of thing publicly, even you think it can't be used against you.

Comment: yeah in the message box

Comment: someone help me please i really need your help

Comment: Note that screenshots of the code and message box are not the right way to include information about your question. You should be able to copy+paste the code, and -- in some cases -- the content of the message box; otherwise you really should add the error from the message box to your question in the form of text. (This will also give you an opportunity to strip out database credentials, which you probably don't want available to the whole Internet.)

Comment: Are you sure these credentials work? Have you tried connecting to the database using something else, such as the MySQL command-line tool, or some sort of GUI such as MySQL Workbench or HeidiSQL?

Comment: try first connecting with a GUI that enables login credentials to test if your login is really working

Comment: it might be a problem with your host credential please double check

Answer (score 0):

You don't have login user mapping set to your db and no high permissions set like db_accessadmin or db_owner or db_reader/writer..

To troubleshoot this issue you can log in using your login and pass and check if you can see the tables, also check your user membership while at it.

If you are creating your db or login from VS don't forget to give those permissions while/after you create the login and user.

Answer (score 0):

What i think you wrote your connection string wrong try this one i even had this problem a time ago another problem can be the connection to the host it means in your mysql settings the remote access is not allowed, IF you have this problem i need to know what operation system are you using linux or windows.

```
 Dim conn As New MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=s_t_d")
    Try
        conn.Open()
        MsgBox("Koneksi Berhasil")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message
    End Try
```